# Under which conditions does (v-w)>(x-y) imply (v*a-w*b)>(x*c-y*d)?

Tags: inequality, finite-differences

I know that

- $(v-w)>(x-y)$
- $(v-w), (x-y) > 0 $
- $(a-b)<(c-d)$
- $(a-b), (c-d)<0$
- $v,w,x,y,a,b,c,d>0$

Can I conclude from this that $(v*a-w*b)>(x*c-y*d)$?

Comment: Using Mathematica, it is not true.